# Dynamic image thumbnails with S3

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Current I've created a small api to handle all thumbnail processing on my application as follows:

```
../thumbnail?src=image.jpg&w=150&height=100
```

This will first check to see if a thumbnail with these parameters for this image has already been generated, if not, it will create it then redirect to it. If it's already there it skips the generation.

My problem now is if I want to upload these thumbnails to S3, how can I check if an image already exists and skip generation?

Ideally I'd make the first request to S3 which would redirect to my thumbnail script if the image doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, the solution is to bypass S3 completely and use Cloudfront which allows the option of getting its content from your servers.

```
something.cloudfront.com/thumbnail?params=...
```

It will look for the image in these cache servers first and if it doesn't find it there it goes to

```
your.domain.com/thumbnail?params=....
```

And it will cache into Amazon from there